# Accessing variables in objects in javascript without "this"

Tags: javascript, variables, object, this

```js
function Peon(number) {
  this.number = number;

  this.inc = function() {
    number = number + 1;
  };

  return true;
}
var p = new Peon(10);

function returnNumber() {
  p.inc();
  alert(p.number);
}
```

```html
<input id="b00" type="button" value="Click" onclick="returnNumber()">
```

This code doesn't work as intended. Is there a way to make it work without having to write

```
this.number=this.number+1;
```

Here it is a trivial choice, but in bigger codes not having this.* would make it a lot more readable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `number` "private", but then you need a *getter*:

```js
function Peon(number) {
  var number = number;

  // increment
  this.inc = function() {
    number++;
  };

  // a simple getter
  this.getNumber = function() {
    return number;
  }
}

var p = new Peon(10);

function returnNumber() {
  p.inc();
  alert(p.getNumber());
}
```

```html
<input id="b00" type="button" value="Click" onclick="returnNumber()">
```

You should read Douglas Crockfords "The Good Parts" for more information on how to use this pattern, there's (limited) a preview available at [Google Books](http://books.google.de/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=javascript+methodical&source=bl&ots=HHtqs7w-iJ&sig=xCtqHpuaEe2T-WquaZp0_k9YBXY&hl=en&ei=3UzgTIKALpD5sgak0MyUDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Also you don't need to return something from the constructor, your `return true` is superfluous.

Comment: You can read about Crockford's private members pattern on his website: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html  It's **very important** to note that if you're going to have a lot of Peons, this private member pattern consumes markedly more memory than just using a property, because each individual object will have its *own copy* of both functions defined within the constructor. They are not, and cannot be, shared between objects. So the tradeoff is privacy v. memory use. Memory consumption is a major problem on IE and Firefox. If you're only going to have a few Peons, it doesn't matter.

Comment: `return true` is indeed superfluous and essentially ignored at the end of a constructor, but returning an object rather than a primitive would not be ignored and would return that object rather than the new `Peon` object.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use `this` to reference properties on the `this` object. Note that `this` in JavaScript is very different from `this` in some other languages, like C or Java. More [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html).

What your code is doing is accessing the `number` argument that was passed into the `Peon` constructor function, rather than the `this.number` property you created in the constructor. Which is why it doesn't work as intended, but doesn't fail, either.

There's no reason to define your `inc` operation *within* the `Peon` constructor function, BTW, and some good reasons not to (every individual object created via `Peon` will get its very own *copy* of that function). So instead, you can define it like this:

```js
function Peon(number) {
    this.number = number;
  
    // Don't return values out of constructor functions, it's
    // an advanced thing to do. In your case, you were returning
    // `true` which was being completely ignored by the JavaScript
    // engine because it's not an object. If you had returned an
    // object, the `this` object created for the `new Peon()` call
    // would have been thrown away and the object you returned
    // used instead.
}

Peon.prototype.inc = function() {
    ++this.number;
};

var p = new Peon(10);

function returnNumber() {
    p.inc();
    console.log(p.number); // shows 11, then 12, etc.
}
```

```html
<input id="b00" type="button" value="Click" onclick="returnNumber()">
```

Or using modern JavaScript features (ES2015+):

```js
class Peon {
    constructor(number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    
    inc() {
        ++this.number;
    }
}

const p = new Peon(10);

function returnNumber() {
    p.inc();
    console.log(p.number); // shows 11, then 12, etc.
}
```

```html
<input id="b00" type="button" value="Click" onclick="returnNumber()">
```

Comment: +1 to both you and @Ivo.  The combination of the two makes for a great answer overall.

Comment: as a side note - why ++this.number instead of this.number++? I know they evaluate slightly differently, but in this use case would be interchangeable. Just curious since I tend to see the this.number++ form more frequently.

Comment: @Matt: My native language is English, in which "verb-noun" is a dramatically more common speech pattern than "noun-verb", and so I write "increment x" (`++x`) rather than "x increment" (`x++`). If I were a native German speaker, I suspect I'd write `x++`. :-) In the vast majority of cases, there's no *real-world* difference. (I emphasize "real-world" because otherwise lurkers will pounce and try to micro-optimize. :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but this is a little more concise

```
this.number++
```

Actually, as a side note, you'd be better off declaring .inc outside the constructor of Peon. You could do this with prototype. That way the inc function is not reconstructed each time you create an object of type Peon.

```
Peon.prototype.inc = function(){
    this.number++;
}
```

Or instead of using `p.inc()` you could do `p.number++`. That's the only way I can think of avoiding the this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The only readable way I can see doing it would be:

```
this.inc = function() {
   this.number++;
};
```

Otherwise, in your "bigger codes" postulation, you could do something like this:

```
this.inc = function() {
   var number = this.number; // obviously simple here.  Imagine more complexity
   number++;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do not need to use 'this' in javascript.  You can access variables via closure instead of 'this'

```js
function createPeon(number) {

  function inc() {
    number = number + 1;
  };

  function getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  return {
    inc,
    getNumber
  };
}
var p = createPeon(10);

function returnNumber() {
  p.inc();
  alert(p.getNumber());
}
```

```html
<input id="b00" type="button" value="Click" onclick="returnNumber()">
```